# Linear Regression with Apache Beam

Tags: apache-beam

How might one go about fitting a large number of linear regressions in a beam pipeline? I have a large csv, and I want to normalize every column (about 500) according to two columns A and B. That is, I would like to get standard residuals for X ~ A + B for each column in the csv X.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

That's an interesting use case. You can do something like so:

```
INDEX_A =  # Something
INDEX_B =  # Something else

parsed_rows = pipeline | beam.ReadFromText(my_csv)
                       | beam.Map(parse_each_line)

def column_paired_rows(row):
  for idx, val in row:
    if idx in (INDEX_A, INDEX_B): continue
    # Yield the values keyed with the independent + dependent variable indices
    yield ((INDEX_A, idx), {'independent_var_value': row[INDEX_A],
                            'independent_var_idx': INDEX_A,
                            'dependent_var_value': val,
                            'dependent_var_idx': idx})
    yield ((INDEX_B, idx), {'independent_var_value': row[INDEX_B],
                            'independent_var_idx': INDEX_B,
                            'dependent_var_value': val,
                            'dependent_var_idx': idx})

column_pairs = parsed_rows | beam.FlatMap(column_paired_rows) | beam.GroupByKey()
```

The `column_pairs` PCollection will group all your elements by `independent, dependent` variable pairs, and then you can run the analysis.

```
def perform_linear_regression(elm):
  key = elm[0]   # KEY is a tuple with (independent variable index, dependent variable index)
  values = elm[1]    # This is an iterable with the data points that you need.
  pairs = [(v['independent_var_value'], v['dependent_var_value']) for v in values]
  model = linear_regression(pairs)
  return (key, model)

models = column_pairs | beam.Map(perform_linear_regression)
```

LMK if you'd like me to add further detail

Comment: Thank you. Your answers to various questions on here have been helpful.

Comment: Glad to help : )